# T-SQL Query to get ending position in a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a result set to which I will provide an input position and a number for iteration. I expect a result of the end position.

```
-------------
ID        
-------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

--------------------------------
InputPosition     Iteration
--------------------------------
4                 6

----------------
ID   Iteration   
----------------
1    5           
2    6 (EndPosition = 2)      
3 
4    1  
5    2
6    3
7    4
```

Hence I need to get the 'EndPosition' for this scenario.

Comment: I'm not quite tracking what you need. Could you explain it differently? How are input & iteration used to get end position?

Comment: In the example, I get the 'InputPosition' from which I start my iteration and traverse through the records in 'ID' result set and find out the position in which my iteration ends. The 'End Position' is what I am looking for.

Comment: Can Iteration be greater than the number of rows?  In other words, will you need to potentially cycle through the results more than once?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If it's over 2012, you can probably use an ORDER BY : OFFSET : FETCH scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how important the tables are to the task at hand. If the answer is *not very*, the following may work for you:

```
declare @input as int = 4
declare @itemCount as int = 7
declare @iterations as int = 6

select
    case when (@input + @iterations - 1) % @itemCount = 0 then 7
    else (@input + @iterations - 1) % @itemCount
end as EndPosition
```

If the tables are important, then you may be able to use this logic in combination with the row_number() function.

Comment: Yes, you are right the table is not important here but the end position is.

Answer (score 1):

This will work only for your sequential number set.

```
declare @table table (id int)
insert into @table (id)
values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7)

declare @inputPosition int = 4
declare @iteration int = 6

;with cte as(
select 
    id,
    row_number() over (order by case when id = @inputPosition then 1 else @inputPosition +1 end) as rn
from @table)

select
    *
from
    cte
where rn = @iteration
```